# How can I open this tr link in a new tab instead of the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I open this in a new tab ?

```
<tr href=".....">
```

here is the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry.. window.open(url);

Comment: forgotten: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: `href` on a `tr` tag? `tr` tags are not links.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');`

Comment: great it works! please tell me, how can I have the hand cursor also? because now it shows the arrow in the link

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos - use css for hand cursor .. something like this `table tr { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open

```
window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank')
```

[SEE MORE](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

add the second parameter

```
.attr('href','_blank')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr').click(function(){
    var win = window.open('http://google.com/', '_blank');
    if (win) {
      // Browser has allowed it to be opened
      win.focus();
    } else {
      // Broswer has blocked it
      alert('Please allow popups for this site');
    }
  })
```